# Preg_replace not working properly for $(dollar) symbol in php

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

In Php Preg_replace When we have using $ then it remove the int near by

example `$pattern = '/\*\|Coupon\|\*/i';
$coupon = '$15t';
$string = 'test coupon *|Coupon|*';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $coupon, $string);`

Then the output is 't' but expected out put in $15t

Comment: Escape the `$` symbol.

Comment: But i need the $ symbol

Comment: Sure, https://ideone.com/SisUBj